# Non Clustered Columnstore Indexes and Primary/Foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

Documentation says that we can't create nonclustered columnstore indexes in primary key or foreign key columns

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql

"
A table with a nonclustered columnstore index can have unique constraints, primary key constraints, or foreign key constraints, **but the constraints cannot be included in the nonclustered columnstore index**. 
"

but on my tests, It is working:

```
CREATE TABLE SimpleTable(  
ProductKey [int] primary key,   
OrderDateKey [int] NOT NULL,   
DueDateKey [int] NOT NULL,   
ShipDateKey [int] NOT NULL) 

GO

insert into SimpleTable values (1,2,3,4)

CREATE nonclustered COLUMNSTORE INDEX IXTEST ON SimpleTable(ProductKey)
```

What am I missing here? Is documentation correct?

Here is my SQL Server version

*Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) - 13.0.4446.0 (X64)   Jul 16 2017 18:08:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition*

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the significance of the statement, as the constraints will still exist on the table, but I imagine, purely based on the language, that what is being said is that the **constraints** cannot be included, but the **columns** can.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I didn't get that. How a constraint will be included in a index? The only way that I think is creating that index with the constraint columns.

Comment: Yeah, I'm unsure on that myself, but I guess that's the point, it can't be included. I guess perhaps, if you're querying a column with a unique index, then the query optimizer won't be able to utilise that index if it has decided to use the nonclustered columnstore index. Best guess! Perhaps someone else will have some insight, but like I mentioned, I don't see the significance of a constraint being "missing" from an index, as it will still exist on the table itself.